# " TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined " I get this error when I using iterate the response list of array in react

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs, redux, react-router

Hi I am using react and redux hooks,I am not able toiterate my Array its show error  " TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined " I am facing this issue in last 2 days. What could I be doing wrong? Here are the codes below . I am new in react please also give suggestion for Improve my code standard as well:

> newproductcomponent.js

```
  import React, { Fragment, useState, useEffect } from "react";
import SidebarRight from "./SidebarRight.component";
import m1 from "../assets/images/m1.jpg";
import m2 from "../assets/images/m2.jpg";
import m3 from "../assets/images/m3.jpg";
import m4 from "../assets/images/m4.jpg";
import m5 from "../assets/images/m5.jpg";
import m6 from "../assets/images/m6.jpg";
import m7 from "../assets/images/m7.jpg";
import m8 from "../assets/images/m8.jpg";
import m9 from "../assets/images/m9.jpg";
import image1 from "../assets/images/image1.png";
import UserService from "../Service/user.service";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";
import {useDispatch, useSelector} from 'react-redux'
import ProductDetails from "./Product/ProductDetails.component";
import { listProduct } from "../Service/Actions/productAction";
import newProduct from "./Product/newProduct";

export default function NewProduct() {

  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const [product, setproduct] = useState([]);
  const [isPDetails, setisPDetails] = useState(true)
  const productList = useSelector(state => state.productListReducer)
  const products = productList.products; 
  useEffect(()=>{
    console.log("render data ")
    dispatch(listProduct());
    setproduct([...product,...productList])
  },[])
  console.log("all product ",productList)

  // useEffect(() => {
  //   UserService.getPublicContent().then(
  //     (response) => {
  //       console.log(response);
  //       setproduct(response.data.post);
  //     },
  //     (error) => {
  //       const _content =
  //         (error.response && error.response.data) ||
  //         error.message ||
  //         error.toString();
  //       setproduct(_content);
  //     }
  //   );
  // }, []);
//  const  handleProductDetails = () =>{
//   setisPDetails(false)
//  }
 
  let productList1;
  let data1 = []
  // setproduct(products.post)
  let data = [{name:"p"},{name:'data'},{name:"frw"}]
  data1.push(products)
  console.log(data1)
  productList1 = product.map((product,index)=>{
    
    debugger
    return (
      // <newProduct res={res}></newProduct>
    <h3 key={index}>Data rendeing {product.price}</h3>
    )

    
  })
  // // productList1 = ({ data }) => {
  //   return (
  //     <Fragment>
        
  //     </Fragment>
  //   )
  // }
  // let proListArray = products.post;
  // if (products) {
  //   productList1 = proListArray.map((res) => {
  //     return (
  //       <newProduct res={res}/>
  //     );
  //   });
  // } 
      return (
        <Fragment>{productList1}
    </fragment>)
```

> productReducer.js

```
import {PRODUCT_LIST_REQUEST,PRODUCT_LIST_SUCCESS,PRODUCT_LIST_FAIL} from '../Constents'


export const productListReducer = (state = {products:[]},action) =>{
    switch (action.type) {
        case PRODUCT_LIST_REQUEST:
            return {loading:true};
        case PRODUCT_LIST_SUCCESS:
            return {loading:false,products:action.payload}
        case PRODUCT_LIST_FAIL:
            return {loading:false,products:action.payload}
        default:
            return state;
    }
}


productAction.js
```

import Axios from 'axios';
import {PRODUCT_LIST_REQUEST,PRODUCT_LIST_SUCCESS,PRODUCT_LIST_FAIL} from '../Constents'

export const listProduct = () => async (dispatch) =>{
dispatch({
type:PRODUCT_LIST_REQUEST
});
try {
const {data} = await Axios.get('http://localhost:5000/api/product/allProduct');
console.log("Action for check", data.post)
dispatch({
type:PRODUCT_LIST_SUCCESS,
payload:data.post
})
} catch (error) {
dispatch({type:PRODUCT_LIST_FAIL,payload:error})
}
}

> Array response of my Api in node.js

> Image of Array Redux store

[image]

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please have a look around, and read through the [help], in particular [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask) I also recommend Jon Skeet's [Writing the Perfect Question](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/) and [Question Checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/). What line of code does the error relate to?

Answer (score 0):

I think there is an initialisation "round" where your variables are not initialized yet.
Try and use a defensive statement where you do nothing (or display a waiting icon) if the variables are not yet initialized.

Comment: I just want to know why my array is not iterate map function is not working in my case .

Comment: `Cannot read property 'map' of undefined` means the variable on which you try to apply the method `map` is undefined which means it has not been given a value yet.

Comment: yes I give the value like Empty array but I get same error

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you need to map elements from `products`, not from the `product`

```
productList1 = products.map((product,index)=>{
    
    debugger
    return (
      // <newProduct res={res}></newProduct>
    <h3 key={index}>Data rendeing {product.price}</h3>
    )

    
  })
```

I see that before using the map, you did not define what the product is.

Comment: I also tried with products but issue are same . I face this problem when i used redux store data . I also tried for diffrent custom object but its work fine with custom array of object

Comment: try ```console.log(product)``` and see what the result in console. The error said that 'product' is ```undefined```, so you can't call ```undefined.map(...)```